# Why won't this conventional HTML form in an Angular template submit?

Tags: angular, forms

I have an Angular 6 component with a HTML form in it, and I'd like the form to work as a conventional HTML form: it should make a `POST` request to the `action` URL and take the user to the response page.  No Ajax.

The problem is, I can click the button all day long, and it doesn't submit.  Is Angular intercepting the "submit" action and preventing it from proceeding?  How do I fix it?

This is the code:

```
  <form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="/url/for/post/request">
    <input type="hidden" name="selecteddata" value="{{userselection}}">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2" [disabled]="userselection.length==0">Submit {{userselection.length}} selection(s)</button>
  </form>
```

What I'm calling `userselection` here is a programmatic property of the component (i.e. defined by `get` and `set` functions) and it doesn't seem to be the source fo the problem.  The `disabled` property works correctly and as long as there's a `userselection` the button is enabled for clicking.

Nothing happens and no error message appears in the console.

I have also tried this with `target="_blank"` in the `<form>` tag, and still nothing happens.  No new tab or window opens.

Comment: Instead of using <button type="submit" try using <input  type="submit"

Comment: @rickz That didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why Angular was intercepting the `submit` event, but combing [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm) I eventually discovered there's a `ngNoForm` directive you can use to prevent Angular from adding a hidden `NgForm` directive.  Adding that tag seemed to fix my problem.  The code is now...

```
  <form ngNoForm method="post" action="/url/for/post/request">
    <input type="hidden" name="selecteddata" value="{{userselection}}">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2" [disabled]="userselection.length==0">Submit {{userselection.length}} selection(s)</button>
  </form>
```